# SQL: Fix for CSV import mistake

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

I have a database that has multiple columns populated with various numeric fields. While trying to populate from a CSV, I must have mucked up assigning delimited fields. The end result is a column containing It's Correct information, but also contains the next column over's data- seperated by a comma.

So instead of Column UPC1 containing "958634", it contains "958634,95877456". The "95877456" is supposed to be in the UPC2 column, instead UPC2 is NULL.

Is there a way for me to split on the comma and send the data to UPC2 while keeping UPC1 data before the comma in tact?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep 2 step process.  pseudo code... `Update table set col2 = right(col1 till the comma)` then` update table set col1 = left(col1 till the comma)` assuming each value has a comma in col 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with string functions. To query the values and verify the logic, try this:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(UPC1, CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) - 1),
  SUBSTRING(UPC1, CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) + 1, 1000)
FROM myTable;
```

If the result is what you want, turn it into an update:

```
UPDATE myTable SET
  UPC1 = LEFT(UPC1, CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) - 1),
  UPC2 = SUBSTRING(UPC1, CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) + 1, 1000);
```

The expression for `UPC1` takes the left side of `UPC1` up to one character before the comma.

The expression for `UPC2` takes the remainder of the `UPC1` string starting one character after the comma.

The third argument to `SUBSTRING` needs some explaining. It's the number of characters you want to include after the starting position of the string (which in this case is one character after the comma's location). If you specify a value that's longer than the string `SUBSTRING` will just return to the end of the string. Using 1000 here is a lot easier than calculating the exact number of characters you need to get to the end.

Comment: Awesome. There are other entries in UPC1 that are still correct. (Anything 8 char long or less is correct) would I be able to run 

`UPDATE myTable where len(UPC1) > 8 SET 
UPC1 = LEFT(UPC1, CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) - 1), 
UPC2 = SUBSTRING(UPC1, CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) + 1, 1000);`

 or something of the sort?

Comment: Since you said "8 char long or less", it would be better to check for a comma in the column by using `WHERE CHARINDEX(',', UPC1) > 0`. Make sure to put the `WHERE` clause last: the way you've got it will be a syntax error.